# Input Prompt in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using Codingforfun dll for InputPrompt and some other things.. I need cancel option in Inputprompt is there anything to configure Inputprompt Cancel button?

Regards dinesh

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Matt's suggestion, WP7 users will *expect* the back button to work as Cancel - and I recently had an app refused for the Marketplace because it didn't use the back button in this way.

Comment: Yup, the guidelines say there needs to be a cancel or no button for every yes or ok confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The `InputPrompt` doesn't have a cancel option. I fyou grab the [source](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61253#1113288) though, you should see that it just extends `PopUp` so it should be easy to add another button to trigger set the `PopUpResult` to be `PopUpResult.Cancelled`.

Comment: they were taking OkButton from OnApplyTemplate which is already created, but for me how to do that for cancel button.. If i have xaml file for input then I can do it easily..